# How do you increase the speed of a rotation animation when hovered with CSS?

Tags: html, css, animation

I have my logo spinning on [my website][1]. When I hover it with a mouse i would like it to spin faster smoothly. At the moment when I hover the logo it simply returns back to its original rotation then starts the new rotation faster. I would like the logo to increase and decrease in speed when hovered without returning to the original rotation.

This is my logo:

```
<img id="logo" src="shilogo.svg" width="50" height="50" alt="Logo">
```

And here is the current CSS:

```
#logo{
    padding:5px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 5s linear infinite;
}

#logo:hover{
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin{
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes spin{
  100% { -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin{
  100% { transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it'll work but try only changing the duration on hover: `animation-duration: 2s;`

Comment: I don't know if you can do this with CSS only. JS would be able to update the speed without resetting the animation.

Answer (score 2):

You should only reset animation-duration to increase speed else the whole rule is reset:*(note: result may varie from a browser to another,...)*

```css
#logo{
    padding:5px;
    animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
}

#logo:hover{
    animation-duration:1s;
}


@keyframes spin{
  100% { transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}
```

```html
<img id="logo" src="http://dummyimage.com/100"  alt="Logo">
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the speed by changing the time. An idea is to rotate a container in the same direction and the overall speed will increase.

Here is an example:

```css
.logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
}

.container {
  margin:10px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition:10s all;
}

.container:hover {
  transform: rotate(-3000deg);
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo"></div>
</div>
```